# Jquery Bootstrap Button Group Checkbox Value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I cant seem to get any of my checkbox/radio button values. The code below is what I think is most logical after reading a lot of posts, but still doesnt work.

My PHP

```
<!-- Account Type -->
<input type="hidden" id="hidden-accounttype">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="accounttype">Account Type</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-custom btn-block" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default col-xs-6 active">
      <input type="radio" name="accounttype" id="accounttype-0" class="button-accounttype" value="broker">Broker
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default col-xs-6">
      <input type="radio" name="accounttype" id="accounttype-1" class="button-accounttype" value="client">Client
    </label>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS

```
$('.button-accounttype').click(function(){
  var values = $(this).val();
  $('#hidden-accounttype').val(values);
  alert($("#hidden-accounttype").val());
});
```

Ive also tried

```
alert($(".active").val());
```

Fiddle (first time making a fiddle so please excuse me if i didnt get the bootstrap/jquery extension settings right)

http://jsfiddle.net/3u7p71z6/

Comment: [Works here](https://jsfiddle.net/kv4yjL5h/). Is there anything you're not sharing with us?

Comment: I posted a fiddle now, thats the rest of the code, i removed the irrelevant input elements. Still doesnt work though.

Comment: Hi david, I added the bootstrap extensions to your fiddle and it stopped working right after that.

Didn't expect that would break it haha. No wonder every solution ive tried fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `input` tag is wrapped within `label` tag, the click event is being triggered by the `label` tag and not the `input` tag. So, I added a class `.labelZ` to both the `label` tags and modified the script as :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.labelZ').click(function(){
        var values = $(this).find("input").val();
        $("#hidden-accounttype").val(values);
        alert($("#hidden-accounttype").val());
    });
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u7p71z6/1/).